# iTerm 3 automatic cd

Tags: iterm2, iterm

I recently downloaded iTerm 3 and I have this issue where it automatically cd's in a certain directory when I type the name.

So for example, I want to run grunt, but there's a grunt directory. So when I type grunt, it doesnt run the CLI command, but it automatically cd's into the grunt directory. How can I turn that off?

For example (output of my console):

```
~ → cd Desktop/dir1
dir1 → ls
dir2
dir1 → dir2
dir2 →
```

when I type `dir2`, it should not automatically assume I want to `cd` right?

Comment: would you like to share more details ? The current working directory when you type grunt, and what happens if you type './grunt' ?

Comment: it seems that it's a settings in my OS X machine. This behaviour also appears on the normal Terminal. What I just want: I dont want the terminal to assume I want to CD in a directory when I type only a directory name.

Comment: can you copy your operations and the output to the body of question ? It seems a setting in ''com.googlecode.iterm2.plist".

Comment: @sel-fish see my edits

Comment: I'm afraid this behavior has nothing to do with iTerm, but caused by your zsh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this behavior has nothing to do with iTerm, but caused by zsh.
You can turn it off by execute:

```
unsetopt AUTO_cd
```

There is a related [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126719/how-to-disable-auto-cd-in-zsh-with-oh-my-zsh) here.

Comment: That's it! Thank you.